# Nested list in python returns empty list during DFS recursion

Tags: python, list, recursion, python-3.6, depth-first-search

I am having a graph dict using defaultdict representing the adjacency list of graph in python3 and want to perform a DFS over this graph.
Now, problem is to find all routes from a starting word beginWord and reach endWord, and I am applying DFS for that recursion + backtracking.

ex.

```
beginWord = "hit"   
endWord = "cog"   
graph : defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'hit': ['hot'], 'hot': ['dot', 'lot'], 'dot': ['dog'], 'lot': ['log'], 'dog': ['cog'], 'log': ['cog']})
```

Output should be like :

```
[["hit","hot","dot","dog","cog"],
  ["hit","hot","lot","log","cog"]]
```

**My approach :**
I am having my graph already made and created two new list : path[] and ans[].
path basically goes on starting from beginWord till it reaches endWord and when it does, I append it to ans variable (now it is a 2-d nested list), then pop the last word from the list to trigger backtracking.
I will continue doing this until all the paths are explored and stored in ans[] list.

**problem :**
ans[] returns empty list but it contains two nested empty lists which indicates it knows that answer is two lists which is true but why did it popped that items ?

**My code :**

```
def DFS(beginWord, endWord, graph, path, ans):

    path.append(beginWord)
    if beginWord == endWord:
        ans.append(path)
        path.pop()
        return

    for i in graph[beginWord]:
        DFS(i, endWord, graph, path, ans)

    path.pop()
```

Note : using extend instead of append for ans[] works (not exactly but I get the path) but why not append ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a single list `path`.  When you modify this list, you modify it everywhere it occurs, including the places that you pushed it onto `ans`.

Instead, you need something like `ans.append(path.copy())` which copies the path before appending it to the answer. Any subsequent changes you make to `path` will not affect what you have already pushed onto `ans`.

Comment: Thanks so much @Frank Yellin for your answer. If I am understanding correctly, then ans (which is 2d list) created reference to path list which was modified and then the same was being reflected in ans list ?

Comment: Correct.  The value you push onto `ans` and the value of the variable `path` both refer to a single value inside Python.  Any changes made to the list are seen by all references.  You need to create a copy of the value so that you have a "new" value that looks just like the old one, but isn't linked to it.